# How to select date from date picker in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am using Java to select a date from date picker in selenium. It is not a textbox. I have tried below code but it is not working. Can anyone please help?

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("jobDate")).click();
        WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("jobDate"));
        List<WebElement> rows=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement cell: columns){
               //Select 28th Date 
               if (cell.getText().equals("28")){
                   cell.findElement(By.linkText("28")).click();
               break;
               }
              }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Below is the html code used for date picker. Please have a look.

```html
<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu ltr single opensright show-calendar" style="top: 652.75px; left: 674.5px; right: auto; display: block;">
<div class="calendar left single" style="display: block;">
<div class="daterangepicker_input">
<div class="calendar-table">
<table class="table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th class="month" colspan="5">
<select class="monthselect">
<option value="0" disabled="disabled">Januari</option>
<option value="1" disabled="disabled">Februari</option>
<option value="2" disabled="disabled">Maart</option>
<option value="3" disabled="disabled">April</option>
<option value="4" disabled="disabled">Mei</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">Juni</option>
<option value="6">Juli</option>
<option value="7">Augustus</option>
<option value="8">September</option>
<option value="9">Oktober</option>
<option value="10">November</option>
<option value="11">December</option>
</select>
<select class="yearselect">
<option value="2017" selected="selected">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>
</th>
<th class="next available">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>ma.</th>
<th>di.</th>
<th>woe.</th>
<th>do.</th>
<th>vrij.</th>
<th>zat.</th>
<th>zo.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="off off disabled" data-title="r0c0">29</td>
<td class="off off disabled" data-title="r0c1">30</td>
<td class="off off disabled" data-title="r0c2">31</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r0c3">1</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r0c4">2</td>
<td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r0c5">3</td>
<td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r0c6">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r1c0">5</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r1c1">6</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r1c2">7</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r1c3">8</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r1c4">9</td>
<td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r1c5">10</td>
<td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r1c6">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c0">12</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c1">13</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c2">14</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c3">15</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c4">16</td>
<td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r2c5">17</td>
<td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r2c6">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r3c0">19</td>
<td class="off disabled" data-title="r3c1">20</td>
<td class="today active start-date active end-date in-range available" data-title="r3c2">21</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r3c3">22</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r3c4">23</td>
<td class="weekend available" data-title="r3c5">24</td>
<td class="weekend available" data-title="r3c6">25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="available" data-title="r4c0">26</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r4c1">27</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r4c2">28</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r4c3">29</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r4c4">30</td>
<td class="weekend off available" data-title="r4c5">1</td>
<td class="weekend off available" data-title="r4c6">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="off available" data-title="r5c0">3</td>
<td class="off available" data-title="r5c1">4</td>
<td class="off available" data-title="r5c2">5</td>
<td class="off available" data-title="r5c3">6</td>
<td class="off available" data-title="r5c4">7</td>
<td class="weekend off available" data-title="r5c5">8</td>
<td class="weekend off available" data-title="r5c6">9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any log? can you print the cell.getText() in console and check what actually is getting printed?

Comment: I have tried that but on console, I am getting 
**JavaScript error: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide-overlay.js, line 274: ReferenceError: Application is not defined
1497955467800 Marionette INFO Listening on port 59173
1497955467837 addons.manager DEBUG Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1497955467838 addons.manager DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1497955467838 addons.manager DEBUG Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
Jun 20, 2017 4:14:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C**

Comment: can you check in chrome?

Comment: Yes. I have checked this in chrome too. but still same behaviour

Comment: i think none of your gettext is matcching to 28. Are you sure is the xpath correct. Can i have the site URL or html DOM?

Comment: Please find the the html code of calender and which xpath you are talking about

Comment: i am not able to find the element with id - jobDate in the html dom

Comment: It is the element, by clicking on which the date picker opens.

Comment: ok. just to make sure tr tag is within this element

Comment: the code looks fine for me and cell.gettext() has to give the dates. instead of link text can you try with xpath "//tr[contains(text(),'28')]"

Comment: tried that, still not working

Comment: is the locator for row's and column,s are correct?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: if it is correct, if we print gettext() in console, we will be getting the numbers na?

Answer (score 0):

For clicking on '28', try below code-

```
cell.findElement(By.xPath("//table[@class='table-condensed']//*[text()='28']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked by below code

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("jobDate")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        int currentDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // get date field
        //System.out.println("date is"+currentDate);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'28')]")).click();

        //select date
```